# Kernel time increases for same number of particles

Tags: cuda

I am trying to run my code on NVIDIA's K10 GPU. I am using 5.0 CUDA Driver and 4.2 CUDA runtime. The problem is that the time taken by the kernel increases with iterations, where each iteration uses the same number of sources and targets (or particles). Because of this, the kernel eventually takes very large times, and the code crashes with runtime error, which says something like "GPU fallen off the bus".

The plot showing the behavior of increasing kernel run time with number of iterations can be seen here:

https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B5QLL4ig3LVqODdmVjNBTlp5UFU

I tried to run the NVIDIA "nbody" example to understand if the same thing happens here too, and yes it does. For the number of particles/bodies (Np) = 1e5 and 10 iterations, code runs fine. For Np=1e5 and iterations= 100, OR Np=1e6 and iterations = 10, code goes into a mode where it hangs the entire system.

When I run my own kernel as well as NVIDIA's nbody example on a different machine with Tesla C2050 NVIDIA card (CUDA Driver version: 3.2, and runtime version: 3.2), there is no problem, and kernel takes the same amount of time for every iteration.

I am trying to understand whats going on in the machine with the K10 GPU. I have tried different combinations of CUDA driver and runtime versions on this machine, and here is what I get:

For 5.0 CUDA Driver, 4.2 Runtime, it just hangs and sometimes says "GPU fallen off the bus".

For 4.2 CUDA Driver, 4.2 Runtime, the codes (nbody as well as my code) crash with error: "CUDA Runtime API error 39: uncorrectable ECC error encountered."

For 5.0 CUDA Driver, 5.0 Runtime, it just hangs and sometimes says "GPU fallen off the bus".

This is a 64-bit linux machine, which we have recently assembled with NVIDIA K10 GPU card. I am using gfortran44 and gcc44.

Please let me know if any other info. is required to track the problem.

Thanks in advance for the help!

M

Comment: my guess is your K10 is overheating.  It's odd for you to assemble a machine by yourself with the K10.  The K10 is normally supposed to be delivered in an OEM-engineered server.  The slowing down occurs as the GPU enters thermal throttling to try and protect itself from elevated temp.  The "fallen off the bus" is a catastrophic event.  What system hardware is this in **exactly** (what OEM, what system model, etc.)?  Have you taken any steps to cool the GPU?  The K10 GPU normally expects to be in a closed-loop monitored thermal environment, with cooling (airflow) managed by the server BMC.

Comment: where did you get the K10, exactly?

Comment: nbody definitely doesn't have this problem on the actively cooled GeForce GTX 680, so it's not a GK104 issue and overheating is definitely a possibility.

Comment: Overheating of K10 may be the cause. I did not assemble the system, the system administrator did, and in my understanding the cooling was  taken care as well. However, I have forwarded these questions to him, and will get back with more details. Thanks for these pointers.

Comment: You can monitor the GPU temp using the `nvidia-smi -a` command from a linux command line.  If you can open multiple sessions, then run this command (which will loop): `nvidia-smi -a -l |grep "Gpu"`  in one session, while running your test app (nbody) in the other session.  I tried this out with nbody on a K10 in our cluster.  I observed (one of the GPU) temps to go up to a max of about 43C before it settled down to 39C (presumably as the server fans ramped up).  If you experience temps up in the 60C or higher range, then I would say cooling is suspect.

Comment: Thanks, I monitored the GPU temperatures in both the machines (with K10 and with Tesla C2050), and in the K10 machine, it rises to 99 C and after that the computer hangs and then the temperature displays "Unknown Error", which makes sense. In the C2050 machine, it rises up to 86 C and remains almost stable there, and the GPU works fine. I think that over-heating is a problem in both the machines. Thanks for helping to figure this out.

Comment: Yikes. Hitting 100 C is bad news. The C2050 starts to slow itself down there and goes into full thermal shutdown at 105 C. You definitely need some better cooling. See [this PDF](http://www.nvidia.com/docs/IO/43395/BD-04983-001_v04.pdf) page 19. Note also that, according to NVidia, the ambient temps at the GPU's air intake should never exceed 45 C.

Comment: The GK104's that are used in the K10 usually run south of 70 C in gaming cards, but I'm not sure what its maximum junction temp is.

Comment: @RobertCrovella: When you ran nbody in your K10 GPU, was it for the default 4336 bodies and for 10 iterations? Can you please run this example using 1e6 bodies and check the GPU temperature. My reason for this question is that, as per your answer to the question, C2050 GPU should be good on its own if the air supply is abundant and outside air temperature is reasonably low. In my case, this GPU is kept in a fairly cool place (T ~ 10 C) and the codes run fine, but the GPU temperature rises to about 86–90 C during a heavy computation. Should I feel concerned for this GPU as well?

Comment: @shadowfax I ran `nbody -benchmark -numbodies=65536` and external to that I ran the test 50 passes using an external script/looping tool (10 iterations per pass).  When I run `nbody -benchmark -numbodies=1000000` (just now) for a single pass (10 iterations), I see temps flatten out around 46C during the test run.  I wouldn't be terribly concerned with 86C as long as you don't see anything much above that, and the GPU appears to run normally.  The system may be in a cool place, but I doubt the air inside the case is at 10C.  Inside of a system may be much hotter than the surrounding air.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Thanks for these results. Here are some numbers for the same run, i.e., -numbodies=1000000 for a single pass in C2050: Ambient Room Temperature: 18C,                                 Reported by nvidia-smi:
IDLE: 39C, Fan Speed 30%;
nBody run: 89C, Fan Speed 45%;
The GPU temperature (with nbody running) did not show any difference at all even with a fan blowing on it. I am assuming that this GPU is good under these conditions because if it was reaching its limits, the fan would have spun much faster than 45%.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm mostly just creating an answer so we can call this question closed, but I'll try to add a few details.

Tesla GPUs come in 2 distinct categories: those with a fan, and those without.  Those with a fan carry (at this time) the "C" designation, although the K20 product family naming will be slightly different:

These are not exhaustive lists:

1. Tesla GPUs with a Fan: C870, C1060, C2050, C2070, C2075, K20c  ("C Class")
2. Tesla GPUs without a Fan: M1060, M2050, M2070, M2075, M2090, K10, K20, K20X ("M class")

(note that there is currently no K10 type product with a fan or "C" designation)

Tesla GPUs **with a fan** are designed to be plugged into a wide variety of PC boxes and chassis, including various workstation and server variants.  Since they have their own fan, they require a supply of inlet air that is below a certain temperature level, but given that, they will keep themselves cool.  As the workload increases, and the generated heat increases, they will spin up their own fan to keep themselves cool.  The main ways you can screw up this process are by either restricting the inlet air flow or by putting it in an ambient air environment that is hotter than its max inlet spec.

Tesla GPUs **without a fan** have something called a passive heatsink and they *cannot* keep themselves cool independently and take a *passive* role in the cooling process.  They still have a temperature sensor, but it becomes the responsibility of the server BMC (baseboard management controller) to monitor this temperature sensor (this is done directly at the hardware/firmware level, independent of any OS or any activity being directed at the GPU), and to direct a level of airflow over the card that is sufficient to keep the card cool based on it's indicated temperature.  The BMC does this by ramping up whatever fans are designed into the server chassis that control airflow over the GPU.  Normally there will be shrouding/ducting within the chassis to aid in this process.  Server manufacturers integrating these cards have a variety of responsibilities and must follow various technical specifications from NVIDIA in order to make this work.

If you happen to get your hands on a Tesla GPU without a fan and just slap it in some random chassis, you're pretty much **guaranteed** to have the behavior as described in this question.   For this reason, Tesla "M" series and "K" series GPUs are normally only sold to OEMs who have undergone the qualification process.

Since the average sysadmin/system assembler is not likely to devise a suitable closed loop fan control system and normally does not have easy access to the necessary specifications defining the temperature sensor and access method, the only klugey workaround if you have one of these that you simply must play with, is to direct a *high level of continuous airflow* over the card, in whatever setting you put it.    Be advised, that this will most likely be noisy.  If you don't have a noisy level of airflow, you probably do not have enough airflow to keep a card cool that is in a high workload situation.  In addition, you should probably keep an eye on GPU temps.  Note that the `nvidia-smi` method for monitoring GPU temps does not work for all M class GPUs (i.e. GPUs without a fan).  Unfortunately, the method of temperature sensor access in Fermi and prior for the M class GPUs (different than the C class GPUs) was such that it could not be readily monitored in-system via the nvidia-smi command, so in these cases you will get no temperature reading from nvidia-smi, making this approach even harder to manage.  Things changed with the Kepler generation, so now the temperature can be monitored both by the nvidia-smi method and by the server BMC at the hardware/firmware level.

C class products with a fan have a temperature that can be monitored with nvidia-smi, regardless of generation.  But this is normally not necessary since the card has it's own control system to keep itself cool.

As mentioned in the comments, all GPUs also have a variety of protection mechanisms, none of which are guaranteed to prevent damage.  (If you throw the card in a fire, there's nothing to be done about that.)  But the first typical mechanism is thermal throttling.  At some predefined high temperature near the maximum safe operating range of the GPU, the GPU firmware will independently reduce its clocks to attempt to prevent further temperature rise.  (If the card is clocked slower, then generally it's ability to generate heat is also somewhat reduced.)  This is a crude mechanism, and when this thermal throttling occurs, something in the cooling arena is *already* wrong.  The card is designed to not enter thermal throttling ever, under normal operating conditions.    If temperatures continue to rise (and there is not much headroom at this point), the card will enter it's final protection mode which is to halt itself.  At this point the GPU has become unresponsive to the system, and at the OS level, messages like "gpu has fallen of the bus" are typical.  This means cooling has *failed* and protection mechanisms have *failed*.

Comment: Thank you very much for this information. This very well explains the situation, in which we are right now. We are seeking help from the vendor, who assembled the system for us.